# SSIS And Foreign Key constraints

Tags: ssis

trying to load some data into a table that has a foreign key constraint.  I know that some of the data will not load due to this constraint.  In the ole destination component i have set redirect row to redirect this bad data into an errors table.  However for some reason the whole batch of data get redirected.  Ive set the component to redirect the row if it errors but it still does the whole batch.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a bulk insert then all rows will be diverted. Uncheck the bulk insert parameter UseBulkInsertWhenAvailable to insert row-by-row (this will be slower, but will stop the insert from being done in a single operation)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141095.aspx

Comment: i changed the Accessmode from fastload to openrowset.  This seems to have sorted the problem